# Recursive function with decimal input prints all numbers from zero till n in binary

Tags: c, recursion

My homework is to write a recursive function that prints all the binary numbers from zero through `n`, an input integer.  It's forbidden to use loops, static variables, arrays, global variables.

For example if the input is 7, the output should be:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

My output:

```
1
10
11
100
101
110
111
```

How can I fix my output with those zeros?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void convert(int num)//converts decimal number to binary
{
    if(num>0)
    {
    convert(num/2);
    printf("%d", num%2);
    }
}

void print_binary_number(int num)
{
    if(num<0)
       return;
    print_binary_number(num-1);
     printf("\n");
    convert(num);

}

int main()
{

    int num;
    printf("Please enter an integer:");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    print_binary_number(num);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: is `n` _always_ a power-of-2 minus 1?  Must `n > 0` hold?

Comment: @chux yes, it is

Comment: Do you mean "Yes, `n` is always a power-of-2 minus 1" **or** "Yes `n > 0` is alway true" **or** both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my solution (with minimal changes to your code):

```
#include <stdio.h>


void convert(int num, int limit)
{
    if(limit>0)
    {
        convert(num/2, limit/2);
        printf("%d", num%2);
    }
}

void print_binary_number(int num, int limit)
{
    if(num>limit)
        return;
    convert(num, limit);
    printf("\n");
    print_binary_number(num+1, limit);
}

int main()
{

    int num;
    printf("Please enter an integer:");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    print_binary_number(0, num);
    return 0;
}
```

The `convert` function now takes two arguments instead of one: In addition to the number to print it also receives `limit`, the user input and final value of our loop. It uses `num` to produce binary digits, but it uses `limit` to decide when to stop printing. This has the effect of producing zeroes until the size of `limit` is reached.

Comment: Probably it causes a stack overflow with a not large number (without -O2 option).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That would surprise me. `convert` is bounded by the number of bits in an `int`, so it runs in constant stack space. `print_binary_number` is the critical part: If the compiler doesn't optimize tail calls, it will use O(n) stack (where n is the input number). But I've reversed a 2 MB file using a single function before (recursing on every byte), and that was 15 years ago. It ran without a problem.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Here's a variant that doesn't use linear stack even with a non-optimizing compiler: http://ideone.com/SrtPI8

Answer (score 1):

One way is to look up the various ways to format "leading zeroes" in C.  However, the way I generally see instructors *wanting* this solved is to handle this as a string processing problem.

The null case is simple: the return is "".

For the next expansion, return two sets of strings: the previous set with "0" in front, and the previous set with "1" in front.  This gives us

```
0
and
1
```

Repeat this process to whatever power of two is needed:

```
00
01
and
10
11
```

Then

```
000
001
010
011
and
100
101
110
111
```

is that enough to get you moving?

Comment: Ooh, I see what you're doing. It's not obvious to me how to parametrize it properly (i.e. to produce numbers up to `n`).

Comment: Use an array of strings.  Continue until the array size is at least your input `n`.  Alternately, take log2(n), round up, and recur that many levels.

Comment: Arrays are not allowed.

Comment: `log2(n)` is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Find out how many zeros there are:

```
#include <limits.h>
#define BITS_IN_INT (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT)
// would keep the strings small and legible, but the above gives the correct value
// #define BITS_IN_INT 8

// recurse until first set bit is reached
int number_of_leading_zeros(int n, int count){
  if(n != 0){
    count--;
    n >>= 1;
    return number_of_leading_zeros(n, count);
  } 
  return count;
}
```

Call above function as

```
 number_of_leading_zeros(counter, BITS_IN_INT);
```

Then print them before the converted number

```
// simple loop, made recursive
void print_leading_zeros(int n){
  if(n != 0){
     putchar('0');
     n--;
     print_leading_zeros(n);
  }
}
```

Feel free to exchange with loops if the must-be-recursion-thing-at-all-cost was a misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: That produces far too many zeros. I got 32 instead of 3 for the sample input of `7`.

Comment: plus one for effort, but I'm not allowed to use other libraris, only `stdio.h`

Comment: `print_leading_zeros` can be simplified to: `void print_leading_zeros(int n) { if (n > 0) printf("%0*d", n, 0); }`

Comment: @Error404 you can set `BITS_IN_INT` as you wish or skip it completely and just use the value you wish `int` to have. With `8` for example, you would get the output your teacher probably  had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The following only incurs a recursion depth of log2(n).  Using recursion with depth of `n` gives recursion a bad name.

No loops, static variables, arrays, global variables.  No string literals either which are array-like yet technically *sequences of characters*.

`print_binary_numbers_ll()` invokes 2 paths at each step.  One with a `'0'`, the other with `'1'`.  Once the least significant bit is reached, `digit_ll` list is printed recursively.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct digit_ll {
  int digit;
  struct digit_ll *previous;
} digit_ll;

void print_ll(const digit_ll *prev) {
  if (prev) {
    print_ll(prev->previous);
    putchar(prev->digit);
  }
}

void print_binary_numbers_ll(int num, digit_ll *prev) {
  if (num <= 0) {
    print_ll(prev);
    putchar('\n');
  } else {
    digit_ll current = { '0', prev };
    print_binary_numbers_ll(num / 2, &current);
    current.digit = '1';
    print_binary_numbers_ll(num / 2, &current);
  }
}

void print_binary_numbers(int num) {
  print_binary_numbers_ll(num, 0);
}

int main() {
  print_binary_numbers(3);
  print_binary_numbers(7);
}
```

Output

```
00
01
10
11
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

---

To print 0 to `n`, even if `n` is not a *power-of-2 - 1*, and still only recurse `log2(n)` maximum depth and not use a linked-list:

```
static void print_b(int value, int limit) {
  if (limit) {
    print_b(value/2, limit/2);
    putchar('0' + value%2);
  }
}

static void print_binary_numberR(int depth, int value, int limit) {
  if (depth) {
    print_binary_numberR(depth/2, value*2 + 0, limit);
    print_binary_numberR(depth/2, value*2 + 1, limit);
  } else if (value <= limit) {
    print_b(value, limit);
    putchar('\n');
  }
}

void print_binary_numbers(int num) {
  print_binary_numberR(num, 0, num);
}

print_binary_numbers(3);
print_binary_numbers(4);
```

Output

```
00
01
10
11
000
001
010
011
100
```

Comment: In case of input `5`. print `000` - `111`, not  `000` - `101`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  OP commented that `n` was [always a power-of-2 - 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076617/recursive-function-with-decimal-input-prints-all-numbers-from-zero-till-n-in-bin/44077780#comment75177988_44076617).  A more robust answer would print `000-101` for `n==5`.

Comment: _always a power-of-2 - 1_  I doubt it.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY A version that does not rely on OP's " power-of-2 - 1" limitation is appended to this answer..